# Maven Java App on Tomcat NoClassDefFoundError Even With Jar Included

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jstl

I have an application running on Tomcat that I've just recently converted to use Maven. My pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Name</groupId>
    <artifactId>Name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>Name</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>inf</groupId>
            <artifactId>inf-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>inf</groupId>
            <artifactId>inf-security</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net-components</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcomponents</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8a</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- ::: springframework ::: -->
        <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version><!-- wersja wymagana przez ehcache-core 2.4.8-->
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>


        <!-- ::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- ::: commons ::: -->
        <!-- ::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.neethi/neethi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-digester/commons-digester -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- :::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- ::: apache ::: -->
        <!-- :::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ::::::::::::- -->
        <!-- ::: log4j ::: -->
        <!-- ::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- ::: fasterxml.jackson ::: -->
        <!-- ::::::::::::::::::::::::: -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-2</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/displaytag/displaytag -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/dsn -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsn</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/mailapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/smtp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/pop3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>pop3</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/imap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>imap</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/gimap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>gimap</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now, when I start Tomcat and run my application, I get the following Exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

type Exception report

message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    <my classes and method>

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:211)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    <my classes and method>

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

In my /WEB-INF/lib folder, I have the following jars:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
cglib-nodep-3.2.5.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-lang3-3.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-net-3.6.jar
curvesapi-1.04.jar
cxf-core-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.13.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.13.jar
displaytag-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dsn-1.5.6.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
ehcache-terracotta-2.4.8.jar
el-api-6.0.26.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.2.jar
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.3.jar
gimap-1.5.6.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.12.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.1.12.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
imap-1.5.6.jar
inf-core-7.1.jar
inf-security-6.2.jar
itext-1.3.jar
itextpdf-5.5.12.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.5.jar
jackson-core-2.5.5.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.5.jar
jasper-el-6.0.26.jar
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar
javax.mail-1.5.6.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcifs-1.3.17.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
jcl104-over-slf4j-1.4.2.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
mailapi-1.5.6.jar
neethi-3.0.3.jar
netcomponents-1.3.8a.jar
poi-3.15.jar
poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar
pop3-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.4.2.jar
smtp-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
terracotta-toolkit-1.3-runtime-3.5.0.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar
tomcat-juli-8.5.15.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar
```

So, I appear to have the correct jar (jstl-1.2.jar) for the javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config class, so why do I get the above Exception when trying to load my application? I've been stuck on this for a full day and am stumped as to what I'm missing. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm unsure what running the dependency tree tells me. I mean, I understand what it is, but how does this help with my current issue? I don't see a jstl jar included multiple times or anything, so unsure what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the dependency tree is too large to paste into the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the dependency as "provided" but it is not provided by Tomcat. So just remove `<scope>provided</scope>` to make Tomcat use the one from the  /WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update:**

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>   
  <groupId>taglibs</groupId> 
  <artifactId>standard</artifactId> 
  <version>1.1.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: This led to a different error -- "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/user/login.jsp (line: 1, column: 62) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:<application_directory>/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV"

Any ideas on that or why?

Comment: I've updated my answer. (Not sure about the version though)

Comment: You, my friend, are fantastic! Thank you, my application is now starting. I think the true issue was the first one you solved by my having "provided" for the javax.servlet dependency and the taglibs was unrelated (but thanks for the quick followup on that one as well). I'm finally in business! Thank you again very much!